# Cordova and Push notification for Windows8

Tags: cordova

I'm using my own solution to manage the GCM, W8 push server and APNS.

I try to find a cordoba push notification plugin to manage both servers.

I found https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
 but it'is "only" iOS and Android.

Is there any plugin available for the 3 notifications servers ?

I take a look on http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/
but it seems I need to use their server (can someone confirm ?)